# Body responsive image bootstrap don't want background-size solution

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

After trying a lot I'm not able to understand why it's not working for me

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>harpal Quiz</title>
    <meta name="quizDescription" content="this is a quiz website">
    <meta name="keywords" content="Quiz"> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?
    family=Old+Standard+TT|Pacifico" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" 
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-
    alpha.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
    <script 
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" 
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href=”~/favicon.ico” rel=”shortcut icon” type=”image/x-icon” />
    <script 
    src=”https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js”></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/home.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="js/quiz.js" > </script>
    <script src="js/validations.js" > </script>
  </head>
  <body  class=" img-responsive or img fluid" >
   <!--both responsive and fluid not working-->
  </body>
</html>
```

css file as below

```
body
{
font-family: 'Old Standard TT', serif;
font-size:18px;
background-image:URL(../images/quiz.jpg);
background-repeat:no-repeat; 
}
```

I don't wanna use background size I want responsiveness
    why it's not getting responsive

Answer (score 0):

This is not working because you add image by css-property. img-responsive class will work if there is any img tag. 
You have to use background-size. 
[There's a good article showing a few techniques](https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)